# Can I skip one submodule when use 'submodule foreach'?

Tags: git, foreach, git-submodules

Sorry, I am not good at git.
I do command:

```
git submodule foreach git checkout r.1.14
```

but one submodule has another name(because of misclick) and of course I have an error. I want to skip only one repo with mistakes from the submodule list.

Can I do something like this?

```
git submodule foreach --exclude="Except.Repo" 'git checkout r.1.4'
```

Comment: The `git submodule` man page shows all the available options for the `foreach` subcommand. You could probably solve this by passing a shell script (maybe something like `git submodule foreach sh -c 'git rev-parse --verify r.1.4 && git checkout r.1.4 || :'`)

Comment: There's also some ongoing work in submodules to help you distinguish between an active/in-use submodule and an inactive/not-in-use submodule. I don't believe this support is complete yet, so the method @larsks outlines is going to be superior in general. Note that the entire command passed *to* `foreach` is run by a shell (currently at least) so you can just supply the part in quotes as the command.